# SQL Server: Need query to get records by comparing one of it's field with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need query to get records by comparing one of it's field with different values

[image]

Here is the my table

**repeated** 1 means Daily
         2 means Weekly
         3 means Monthly

I need **query** to get all records which are going to Tele caste and being Tele casting by comapring current date and time.

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried? Not sure what you mean - you want to see current running programs and future programs based on actual date and time?

Comment: Well I didn't get it. What do you try to get as a result on the given table? Can you explain it as example on supernatural?

Comment: You'll need to model some kind of duration field as well, or do all shows run for an exact length (e.g. 1 Hour)?

Comment: do you mean you want to know wha tis on in the next say 30 mins based on repeating schedules starting at that date and time with that frequency?

Comment: Please could you show the results that you expect?

Comment: @StuartLC  yes there is duration please check image

Comment: @CeOnSql actually i have not tried at . I'm getting all result which are matched with current date and time  then filtering required records with php coding . I think this is not correct practice so that i'm asking for `SQL QUERY`

Comment: how do you define a monthly schedule? same day of the month?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
--case for daily: only need to check times
select 
    *
from 
    schedules
where
    repeated = 1
    --this is to compare if it starts within the next hour, may have bugs not tested
    --logic is if start time - 1 hour is less than now but start time is more than now must start within the next hour
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ), dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ) < DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())  
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, startdate), startdate)   > DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now()) 

union

--case for weekly: is the day of the week the same, if so check times
select 
    *
from 
    schedules
where
    repeated = 2
    and datepart(dw,startdate) = datepart(dw,Now)
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ), dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ) < DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, startdate), startdate)   > DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())  

union

--case for monthly is the day of the month the same, if so compare times
select 
    *
from 
    schedules
where
    repeated = 3
    and datepart(day,startdate) = datepart(day,Now)
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ), dateadd(hour,startdate),-1) ) < DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, startdate), startdate)   > DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())
```

and is monthly based on date of the month , number of weeks (e.g. 4) or week of the month + weekday (e.g. second tuesday of the month)

EDIT: i think that should work where a monthly cycle is means on that day of the month every month.

The above could be modified to use a separate time column by just using that field for all time comparisons e.g.:

```
...
where
    repeated = 3
    and datepart(day,startdate) = datepart(day,Now)
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, dateadd(hour,starttime),-1) ), dateadd(hour,starttime),-1) ) < DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())
    and DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, starttime), starttime)   > DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, Now()), Now())
```

EXPLANATION:

the normal way i would process this question as a human would be:

- whats the start date
- whats the repeating cycle
- does startdate * any multiple of repeating cycle period = today
- if so is it on now

this is a procedural, step based solution

when i think of this as a set based problem then i need to know what is the set of programs that is on now

I am allowed to add sets (union) but i cannot step through rows considering each one.. so i split it into three sets and add them together:

- daily shows are on every day so i only need to check times
- weekly shows are on every week on the same day, so if its weekly if the days of the week matches compare times
- monthly shows are on the same day of the month every months, so if its that day of the month compare the times

hope this helps.. sorry if my explanation is crap, just trying to help :D

Comment: sorry there is a really stupid bug in this.. fixing, its ignoring the date

Comment: maybe fixed.. hopefully someone knows a better way of comparing times that this :) do you know what you are asking for?

Comment: I think you have not getting my problem

Comment: Actually I'm implementing api for mobile application
suppose some body calls api now i have to return him with all programs which are going to telecast from now only today
for suppose see recordNo # 13 supernatural is program which is of repeated type is 2
mean supernatural will telecast weekly if current date match with `startDate+weekdays(6)=currentDate` have to return this also.I never pass repeat type with query

Comment: you want a query to return what is showing now? - I think the above query does what you ask. except you have not specified a duration when i wrote it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80980/discussion-between-manikanta-g-and-gordatron).

Comment: is there `daydateadd` function sql?

Comment: Just DATEADD as far as i am aware.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx `SELECT DATEADD(day,1,Now()) AS Tomorrow`

Comment: I thought this was the right approach but after reading the chat I'm not really sure anymore. I was going to add that your solution would probably also need to handle broadcasts that started before midnight.

Comment: post your original working php code for that solution and i am sure it can be accomodated.. you only need to mess with where clauses, you could add more selects to the union to cover more cases

Answer (score 0):

Example:

`SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, value3)`

You mean something like that?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this :-

```
Declare  @Today Datetime

Select   @Today = Getdate()

Select   s.ProgramId
        ,s.ProgramName
From    schedules As s With (Nolock)
Where   (Cast(s.startdate As Datetime) + Cast(s.StartTime As Datetime)) >= @Today
Order By s.repeated
        ,s.ProgramId
```